# Angular Material: md-tabs with no default selected tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is there any way of defining tabs without a default active/selected tab?
If I use any value other than an integer, the first tab will always become active.

There is an example in this [pen](http://codepen.io/marcossffilho/pen/xboayr):

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .run(['$rootScope', function($rs) {
    $rs.selectedNegative = -1
    $rs.selectedUndefined = undefined
    $rs.selectedNull = null
    $rs.selectedString = 'none';
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: will not work with versions 0.9 and greater.

Try to set it to a value different from -1, such as -2:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .run(['$rootScope', function($rs) {
        $rs.selectedNegative = -2
      $rs.selectedUndefined = undefined
      $rs.selectedNull = null
      $rs.selectedString = 'none';
  }]);
```

Apperantly they check for -1 values, and then set the active tab as 0. All non numbers values gets ignored also, and ended with 0.

See this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYJGoB).

Comment: This way doesn't work anymore, the latest version patched this up... :(